# Trying to install_tensorflow

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use `keras` and `tensorflow` in R.

I am having this issue:

I use my libraries `keras` and `tidyverse` as I code `library(keras)` and `library(tidyverse)`. However, that does not work and the Console says I need to install Tensorflow as such: by using `install_tensorflow`. I do that, but then, the console says this: could not find function `install_tensorflow`. I tried a number of things. I believe I have downloaded everything correctly. Below is a codeblock of what I have:

```
#install.packages("keras", dependencies = TRUE)
library(keras)
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("tensorflow")
#py_install("tensorflow") #trying the py version after checking online how to resolve this issue
#install.packages("reticulate")
#library(reticulate)
install_tensorflow()
```

Note that I have tried a number of things as shown by the # sign (comment sign).

Can somebody please help me fix this issue?

Thank You!

I have explained what I have tried in my details of the problem.

Comment: first install tensorflow, then open rstudio `install.packages("tensorflow")` ,`library(tensorflow)`

Comment: Try `tensorflow::install_tensorflow()`